# How to register the personal certificate on windows?

Tags: ssl, certificate, visual-c++

I want to register a personal certificate on windows, so the web server can verify the client's identity. Here is my code (It's hard for me to find the example,so I don't know whether is right or not):

```
char* pfile = "d:/client.crt";
FILE* fp = fopen(pfile, "r");
char ch;
char buf[10000] = {0};
int i = 0;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)  {
    memcpy(buf+i, &ch, 1);
    i++;
}

BYTE pBinByte[8192] = {0};
unsigned long binBytes = 8192;
//decode base64
CryptStringToBinaryA( buf, strlen(buf) ,CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER , pBinByte , &binBytes ,NULL,NULL);

HCERTSTORE hMyCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, _T("MY"));

int len = binBytes;
PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(
    MY_ENCODING_TYPE,
    pBinByte,
    len);
BOOL addOK = CertAddCertificateContextToStore(
    hMyCertStore,
    pCertContext,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING,
    NULL);
CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);

CertCloseStore(hMyCertStore, 0);
```

After I run the code in the xp, it run success. And I can find the certificate in the certmgr.msc.
But I can't see it in the IE browser's setting.
How can I fix that problem? Please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.crt file does not contain  private key and to make that work you may wanna install a .pfx file that has both public and private keys. And to install this you can simply double click the file then click install certificate then just complete the import wizard and it will automatically store the certificate under your "Personal" folder of your keystore.

Comment: Now, I can install some .cer file to CA or ROOT. But can't install to "MY" stort.

Comment: Hi,I want to know how to convert from .cer to .pfx in vc program? Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, can use PFXImportCertStore() to install pfx certificate. And I found that the CA certificate can be cer formate.